# How do I update MySQL column depend on last date

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say I have two tables

table_1

```
ID  Name   Status
1   John   
2   Peter  
3   Smith
```

table_2

```
ID  UID   Status  UpdateDate
1   1     B       2010-05-05
2   1     C       2011-03-02
3   3     C       2011-03-02
4   2     A       2011-03-02
```

What is the correct statement to update `Status` on `table_1` according to `UpdateDate` on `table_2`.

Result should be like this

table_1

```
ID  Name   Status
1   John   C
2   Peter  A
3   Smith  C
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE table_1 SET Status = (
    SELECT Status FROM table_2
    WHERE UID = table_1.ID
    ORDER BY UpdateDate desc
    LIMIT 1
    );
```

Comment: Thanks Kyle. How do I know update will use the latest `UpdateDate`

Comment: @hmmmm - By utilizing `ORDER BY UpdateDate desc` you utilize the latest date - Also apologies, I added `LIMIT` instead of `TOP` now that I see you're using MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

To get the status for each UID:

```
SELECT UID, Status
FROM (
  SELECT UID, MAX(UpdateDate) LastUpdateDate
  FROM table_2
  GROUP BY UID
) l
JOIN table_2 t ON t.UID = l.UID AND t.UpdateDate = l.LastUpdateDate
```

To update:

```
UPDATE table_1 SET Status = l.Status
FROM table_1 t
JOIN (
  SELECT UID, Status
  FROM (
    SELECT UID, MAX(UpdateDate) LastUpdateDate
    FROM table_2
    GROUP BY UID
  ) l
  JOIN table_2 t ON t.UID = l.UID AND t.UpdateDate = l.LastUpdateDate
) l ON l.UID = t.ID
```